# Canon printer driver MG5420

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I went to link that was provided by cochisebt:

[Search for drivers, manuals and firmware for PIXMA MG5440](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5440.aspx)

Downloaded this file `mcp6-mac-mg5400-10_84_2_0-ea13` into my download folder.

I have Ubuntu 13.10 OS,  Now how do I get it installed from this location? New at this.

Comment: I downloaded both of those suggested drivers you indicated below into my download folder. These are tar.gz file packages. I don't know the steps I have to take next to add them to the printer lists with in the add printer app or prepare them for use.I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have downloaded the Mac Driver. You need to read carefully on that site what you Download. 
Your file should be: [This one](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5440.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:13-994983&page=1&type=download)

Filename is:  cnijfilter-mg5400series-3.80-1-deb.tar.gz

After downloading unpack it and then simply click on it. Software center will open and you can install it from there.

Comment: It could possibly be [this](http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/Fax__Multifunctionals/InkJet/PIXMA_MG_series/PIXMA_MG5440.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:13-994987&page=1&type=download) one as well.... Try that if the above one does not work.

Comment: rechengehirn, Thanks to you; this driver package had both the 32 bit and 64 bit machine drivers, I installed it as you advised and it works very good on both my OS, ubuntu 13.10 and linux Mint 16. Tomorrow I will be installing on my friends 64 bit Lap top. Thanks. Phil

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Gutenprint drivers. Gutenprint has great support for Canon printers, and your model is supported. This post shows how to install the Guttenprint driver: https://askubuntu.com/a/1253141/595992

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.