# Canon printer driver issue

Tags: drivers, printing, deb, canon, rpm

I have been trying to install the driver for my canon printer but I always get the error shown below. I also tried to convert the package from .rpm to .deb and try it to run it from there, but again it does not work.

```
jorge@jorge-VPCEH3N6E:~/Downloads/cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-rpm$ 
sudo bash install.sh
[sudo] password for jorge: 
==================================================

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver

Version 4.00
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2013

All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
An error occurred. A necessary package could not be found in the proper location.
```

Can someone let me know where can a get the file -deb??
Thanks

Comment: http://www.askmeaboutlinux.com/?p=3124

Links at that article lead you to a .deb

Comment: I would suggest going here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100550201.html and click to download and SAVE what will be cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz and it should end up in your Downloads folder; if you copy the commands that follow one by one; paste into a terminal; hit the ENTER key; and the final install script command should do all for you `cd Downloads` then `tar -zxvf cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb.tar.gz` then `cd cnijfilter-mg2500series-4.00-1-deb` and then `./install.sh` will ask you for your sudo password

Comment: Did any of the comments or answers work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where to find the Linux drivers for Canon printers. The official Canon site doesn't even have a Linux driver for my printer. Luckily, the Gutenprint driver works well for Canon printers. You can install it as follows:

```
sudo apt install printer-driver-gutenprint
```

Then, connect your printer via USB to the computer, and go to **Settings > Printers**.

[image: Printers dialog]

If you don't see your printer there, add it. If you see the printer, click on the gear icon next to it, and select printer details. On the new window that opens up, select **Select from database...**

[image: MP470-series details]

Find your printer model under the Canon drivers.

[image: Canon drivers list]

Once you save that, your printer should work :)

I tested this solution both in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 using a Canon PIXMA MP470 series printer, and I could see an entry for the MG2500 series printer too.