# What printer driver should i use for Canon imageRUNNER ADVANCE C3530i?

Tags: 18.04, canon

The Canon imageRUNNER ADVANCE C3530i is not listed in "Select Printer Driver" when adding printer to my computer. What printer driver should i use for Canon on ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Did the answer work?

Answer (score 1):

Gutenprint offers more Canon printer's support than the driver installed by default in Ubuntu. I did not find one specifically for your printer, but a driver for a similar supported printer might work. I would try the ones for Canon iR-ADV C3325/C3330 Foomatic/Postscript, Canon iR-ADV C3325/C3330 PPD, Canon iR-ADV C5030/C5025 Foomatic/Postscript, and Canon iR-ADV C5030/C5025 PPD. Hopefully one of those works.

Check out my answer here for how to install it, and how to configure it: https://askubuntu.com/a/1253141/595992

Configure one of the drivers listed avobe. Then, test if the printer works. If it does, enjoy :). If it doesn't, try a different one. Hopefully, one of them works. Good luck!